# Change hosts file does not have any effect

Tags: macos, dns, hosts, ping

I have edited the /etc/hosts file on macOS 10.12.6. Then trying to flush the DNS services has no effect, why?

Here is what I have done:

```
cd /etc
sudo cat hosts
sudo cat -te hosts
##$
# Host Database$
#$
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface$
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.$
##$
127.0.0.1^Ilocalhost$
255.255.255.255^Ibroadcasthost$
::1^Ilocalhost$
127.0.0.1^Ipagead46.l.doubleclick.net$
$
$

ping pagead46.l.doubleclick.net
PING pagead46.l.doubleclick.net (172.217.23.66): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.23.66: icmp_seq=0 ttl=56 time=678.921 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.23.66: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=35.715 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.23.66: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=52.304 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.23.66: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=48.495 ms
^C
--- pagead46.l.doubleclick.net ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 35.715/203.859/678.921/274.346 ms


dscacheutil -flushcache
ps -ef | grep mDNS
    0  1777     1   0  6:46PM ??         0:00.11 /usr/sbin/mDNSResponderHelper
   65  1916     1   0  8:17PM ??         0:00.07 /usr/sbin/mDNSResponder
  501  1929  1013   0  8:19PM ttys007    0:00.00 grep mDNS

dscacheutil -flushcache
sudo killall mDNSResponder
sudo killall mDNSResponderHelper
ps -ef | grep mDNS
   65  1933     1   0  8:20PM ??         0:00.03 /usr/sbin/mDNSResponder
  501  1936  1013   0  8:20PM ttys007    0:00.00 grep mDNS

sudo cat -te hosts
##$
# Host Database$
#$
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface$
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.$
##$
127.0.0.1^Ilocalhost$
255.255.255.255^Ibroadcasthost$
::1^Ilocalhost$
127.0.0.1^Ipagead46.l.doubleclick.net$
$
$

ping pagead46.l.doubleclick.net
PING pagead46.l.doubleclick.net (172.217.23.66): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.23.66: icmp_seq=0 ttl=56 time=43.226 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.23.66: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=39.457 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.23.66: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=36.937 ms
^C
--- pagead46.l.doubleclick.net ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 36.937/39.873/43.226/2.584 ms
```

`cat -te ...` shows a ^I for tabs and a $ for newline to show what is exactly
in the file.

None of my browsers (Safari or Chrome) seem to honor the new hosts entry.

I am most certainly doing something wrong here, any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend  [Gas Mask](http://clockwise.ee) (freeware, no affiliation) which not only eliminates the need to try hack it in terminal, but also allows you multiple versions of the hosts file, switchable on the fly, instant response.

[image]

To use, Create a new file - it will setup the defaults automatically. Copy/paste any existing setup you want to carry over from any file to any other. Add any new data in the same format - it's very lenient on formatting, tab or space.
Save, then activate.
You can swap profiles any time the app is running, otherwise your last chosen will persist.
Activating a profile makes it immediately available.
 <sub>Note: the use of 127.0.0.1 rather than localhost for IPV6 is non-standard, but just seems to make the Mac behave better</sub>

Comment: I can give it a try, looks good - but actually I tried to find the -why- answer and with the Gas Mask tool I will probably never find out. Tnx for responding.